# Firebase Test Lab and Play Store internal testing app fails to install with INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK message

Tags: android, firebase, apk, android-app-bundle, google-play-internal-testing

I am facing an issue with the signed build during Firebase Test Lab and Play Store Internal Testing pre-launch report with this message - app fails to install (INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK).

Attached screenshots for reference.

The issue occurs only with the app bundle (.aab file) creation however it does not appear in the .apk. I have tested .apk file on Firebase Test Lab which succeeded. The .apk file no longer supported on the Play Store now so I can't upload that file type in Internal Testing.

It looks like the issue is with app bundle creation process in Android Studio, but Test Lab or Play Store does not give enough information so it is getting complex to trace this issue.

If someone faced same issue then please assist, how I can fix this.

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.

[image: play_store_internal_testing]

[image: firebase_test_lab]

- I cross-checked signing information, that is correct.
- Generated .apk with same signing information and tested on Test Lab which worked but .aab file failed.
- Clean the project and then generated new build, but no luck.
- Tried rest of the solutions available online but failed.
- App SDK Minimum Version - 21
- App SDK Maximum Version - 34
- Android Studio Version - 17.0.9

**SOLUTION**

I was in continues conversation with Firebase, they suggested a solution as you can see in the screenshot and the solution worked for me. Attaching the screenshot so this may help others.

Thanks to Firebase Support Team.

[image: firebase-solution]

Comment: I got same problem... Seems to be recent change

Comment: @Aure77 I am in a conversation with Firebase, they are looking into the issue. I will keep updating here.